# Share counter between amsthm and algorithm

Tags: algorithms, amsthm

I am using `amsthm`

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
```

and `algorithm`

```
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}
%\@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter}
\makeatother
```

In my text I have everything numbered consecutively in each chapter (Definition 3.1, Lemma 3.2, Theorem 3.3) except for the algorithms which have separate counter (Definition 3.1, Lemma 3.2, Algorithm 3.1, Theorem 3.3). How can I make it so that algorithms are numbered together with everything else? (Definition 3.1, Lemma 3.2, Algorithm 3.3, Theorem 3.4)

Comment: use `[algorithm]` in all your `\newthorem` so they use that instead of `thm`

Comment: It's weird I was unable to google that. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: There are many posts using the [share counter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=share+counter) term. Consider looking at those...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[algorithm]` in all your `\newthorem` so they use the `algorithm` counter instead of `thm`.

Beware though, if you use a floating environment and a non-floating environment with the same counter the algorithm may float past the theorem so come in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I needed a different solution since I didn't have access to `\newtheorem` definitions.

```
\newcounter{common} % Create counter "common"

\makeatletter
\let\c@theorem\relax % drop existing counter "theorem" (you might not need this)
\makeatother

\usepackage{aliascnt}
\newaliascnt{theorem}{common} % let "theorem" be an alias for "common"
\newaliascnt{algorithm}{common} % let "algorithm" be an alias for "common"
```