# How to get a correct reference for shared counters of amsthm and algorithm2e

Tags: lyx, algorithm2e, amsthm

I tried to have the same counter for the AMS and algorithm2e algorithm-environment with

```
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\makeatletter
\let\c@algocf\relax
\makeatother
\newaliascnt{algocf}{thm}
```

as described here [Share counter between amsthm and algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244393/share-counter-between-amsthm-and-algorithm).

Here is my MWE code. It is created with Lyx, as this is what I use for my thesis.

```
%% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}
  \theoremstyle{plain}
  \newtheorem{lyxalgorithm}[thm]{\protect\algorithmname}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
% algorithms
\usepackage[linesnumbered,algoruled,boxed,lined,english]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\makeatletter
\let\c@algocf\relax % drop existing counter
\makeatother
\newaliascnt{algocf}{thm}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
  \providecommand{\algorithmname}{Algorithm}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{lyxalgorithm}
\label{alg1}
Do stuff.
\end{lyxalgorithm}
\begin{algorithm}[H] 
\label{alg2}
Do other stuff.
\caption{$\leftarrow$ Prints the correct number 2}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{lyxalgorithm}
\label{alg:alg3}
Just be!
\end{lyxalgorithm}

Here is a reference to Algorithm \ref{alg1}, Algorithm \ref{alg2} and Algorithm \ref{alg:alg3}.    
\end{document}
```

How do I make \ref{alg2} print the correct number 2 instead of 1?

Comment: unrelated to aliasing, `\label` has to be after `\caption` if you want it to use the captions number.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you include algochapter in this line:"\usepackage[linesnumbered,algoruled,boxed,lined,english,**algochapter**]{algorithm2e}"

You would also have to put \newaliascnt BEFORE \newtheorems

Also, \newaliascnt{algocf}{thm} lets "algocf" be an alias for "thm", which is not really what you want because, algocf is already defined to be the counter for algorithm2e, and it cannot be the alias for another counter. It should be \newaliascnt{thm}{algocf}.

Here is a link that might help: [Algorithm with chapter number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124902/algorithm-with-chapter-number)