# Numbering of theorems, lemmas, definitions, examples, etc for thesis

Tags: thesis, preamble, report

I am trying to work on the numbering of the theorems/definitions/lemmas etc., and I have some problems with the numbering.

I would like the theorems, propositions, corollaries, definitions, conjectures, examples to follow the same numbering, and to reduce the numbering. For example, in my code below, the stuff goes as follows:

Chapter 1

Addition

1.1 Basics (SECTION)

Definition 1.1

Theorem 1.2

Theorem 1.3

Example 1.4

1.1.1. Some tips (SUBSECTION)

Definition 1.5

1.2 Advanced stuff (SECTION)

Definition 1.6

**But how would I get it to be like this below?**

Chapter 1

Addition

1.1 Basics (SECTION)

Definition 1.1.1.

Theorem 1.1.1.

Theorem 1.1.2.

Example 1.1.1.

1.1.1. Some tips (SUBSECTION)

Definition 1.1.2.

1.2 Advanced stuff (SECTION)

Definition 1.2.1.

**We have used the following environment:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{mnnit}
%\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{thesis}
%\chapapp{Chapter}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
%\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\Large} {{Chapter~}\Large\thechapter}
%{2ex}
%{}
%[]

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{llncsdoc}
\usepackage{mmm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
%\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epsfig,float}
\usepackage{cases,textcomp, amssymb, amsmath}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array,longtable,wallpaper,graphicx,epsfig,subfigure,float,booktabs, pdfpages}
%\usepackage{rotating,setspace,enumerate,morefloats,xcolor,threeparttable}
\usepackage[left=1.3in,right=1.2in,top=1.4in,bottom=1.35in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{tocbasic}
%\usepackage[subnum]{cases}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%\usepackage{makeidx} 
%\usepackage{fancyhdr,multirow,lscape,chngpage,calligra,float}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}
%\usepackage{titletoc}
%\usepackage{watermark}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage{afterpage}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{multirow,lscape,chngpage,calligra,float}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem{dfn}[thm]{Definition}
%\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
%newtheorem{ex}[thm]{Example}
%\newtheorem{remex}[thm]{Remarks and Examples}
%\newtheorem{pro}[thm]{Proposition}
%\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
%\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
%\newtheorem{no}[thm]{Note}
%\newtheorem{ope}[thm]{Open Problem}
%\newtheorem{que}[thm]{Question}

%\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof] {\begin{trivialist}
%\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}] } {\end{trivialist}}

\makeindex

%\setcitestyle{square}
\def\tableshortname{Table}
\def\figureshortname{Figure}

%\def\bibname{Bibliography}
%\includeonly{titlepage}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document}
%
%\newpage
%\include{Symbols}
%\include{Abstract}
%\include{Publication}
%\include{References}

%\include{presentations}

\newpage
\include{title}

\newpage
\include{Certificate}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\newpage
\include{Acknowledgments}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newpage
\tableofcontents

    \mainmatter 
    \include{Symbols}
    \include{Introduction}
    \include{Chapter2}
    \include{Chapter3}
    \include{Chapter4}
    \include{Chapter5}
    \include{Chapter6}
%   \include{Chapter7}
%   \include{conclusion}    
    \include{References}
    \printindex
\include{Publication}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help). Please show us,what you've already tried and how the definitions, theorems, examples etc. are currently defined. For example `amsthm`'s `\newtheorem` has an optional argument to share a counter.

Comment: The answer will depend on how you're defining the defintion/theorem/example environment, if you've got some code put it here and you'll get more help, if you don't have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244393/share-counter-between-amsthm-and-algorithm) question for a set up that does this, ignore the algorithm bits

Comment: \usepackage{cases,textcomp, amssymb, amsmath}

Comment: \usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{llncsdoc}
\usepackage{mmm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epsfig,float}
\usepackage{cases,textcomp, amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}

Comment: @VipulSingh Please add a compilable reproducible example to your question, not in comments. The code should start with your class, include all the necessary packages and a short test document to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @VipulSingh Please also edit the title of your question to reflect the actual problem you are asking about. This will help future users with the same problem to find your post.

Comment: You've posted a list of the packages you load -- quite a few of them more than once -- in a comment. According to this list, you employ neither the `amsthm` nor the `ntheorem` package. How then do you create theorem-like environments at present? Please be specific.

Comment: As an aside, your original title looked a lot like spam (we get a metric buttload of "pay us and we will help you cheat with your paper" spam); going forward, please try to come up with a title which adequately summarizes the actual problem you want help with.